# Hello everyone, I need help, for react native launch icon

Tags: android, react-native

I am struggling to keep it uniform in my android mobile and android tablet. I am placing my android icon in assets/logo.png and then creating other icons for all devices using react-native set-icon --path  --background  --platform 
I don't know why the app icon on the tablet is without a corner radius whereas on mobile it is okay!

[Tablet version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi7lt.jpg)

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRIDS.jpg)

It will be great if anyone can help me??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed an asset for the tablet's target DPI. I would recommend you use android studio to generate appropriate assets.

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio)

1. open project in android studio
2. Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset
3. set Icon type to "Launcher icons"
4. customize and save